# Bootstrap multiple div collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

im in the middle of building my website using bootstrap as my base I was at a flying state but now I have a issue with a multiple div collapse and I cannot seem to figure out whats causing it any suggestions ?

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
    <h1 class="mt-4 mb-3">FAQ</h1>

    <ol class="breadcrumb">
       <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
       <li class="breadcrumb-item active">FAQ</li>
    </ol>

    <div class="mb-1" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

        <!-- NestPanel-1 - Start -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">General</a></h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card" id="accordion">
                        <!-- NestPanel-1 Inner-1 - Start -->
                        <div class="card-default">
                            <div class="card-header"><h6 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseInnerOne">Product</a></h6></div>
                            <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="card-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#GeneralInfo" aria-expanded="true">
                                               test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="GeneralInfo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                        test
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#GeneralInfo1" aria-expanded="true" >
                                             test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="GeneralInfo1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
                                        test
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- NestPanel-1 Inner-1 - End -->

                        <!-- NestPanel-1 Inner-2 - Start -->
                        <div class="card-default">
                            <div class="card-header"><h6 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseInnerTwo">Services</a></h6></div>
                            <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="card-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#GeneralServices" aria-expanded="true">
                                              test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="GeneralServices" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
                                          test
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#GeneralServices1" aria-expanded="true" >
                                               test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="GeneralServices1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
                                         test
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#GeneralServices2" aria-expanded="true" >
                                                  test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="GeneralServices2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
                                           test
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- NestPanel-1 Inner-2 - End -->

                        <!-- NestPanel-1 Inner-3 - Start -->

                        <div class="card-default">
                            <div class="card-header"><h6 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseInnerThree">Care</a></h6></div>
                            <div id="collapseInnerThree" class="card-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#GeneralCare" aria-expanded="true" >
                                              test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="GeneralCare" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
                                            Please <a href="contact.php">Contact us</a> and a member of staff will be able to assist you further.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- NestPanel-1 Inner-3 - End -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- NestPanel-1 - End -->


    </div>
    <div class="mb-1" id="accordion1"  role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

        <!-- NestPanel-2 - Start -->





        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="answerOne">Windows & Doors</a></h5>
            </div>


            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="answerOne">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card" id="accordion1">
                        <!-- NestPanel-2 Inner-1 - Start -->
                        <div class="card-default">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h6 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOuterOne">Guarantees</a></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOuterOne" class="card-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="card-body">







                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingTwo">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#WDGuarantee" aria-expanded="true">
                                test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="#WDGuarantee" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion1">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
       test
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                  

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- NestPanel-2 Inner-1 - End -->

                        <!-- NestPanel-2 Inner-2 - Start -->

                        <div class="card-default">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h6 class="mb-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOuterTwo">Care</a></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOuterTwo" class="card-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <div class="faq-header" id="headingThree">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                           <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#WDCare" aria-expanded="true">
   test
                                           </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="#WDCare" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion1">
                                        <div class="card-body" >
test 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                      

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- NestPanel-2 Inner-2 - End -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- NestPanel-2 - End -->

    </div>

    <div class="mb-4" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                   <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Conservatories</a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="card-body">


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

It seems that the first section is working perfectly fine however the second section isnt responding, I dont know if im having a blonde moment here or what ?

Comment: The markup provided seems to work fine here: https://www.bootply.com/v79ZnK717E do you have additional code that may be causing an issue in your environment?

Comment: sorry jcruz if you select windows and doors then click care and click on the question it doesnt open

Comment: try now, you had a # in your ID as well... removed it and windows > care > test works fine

Comment: issue with the id *#WDGuarantee*. change ```<div id="#WDGuarantee" ``` this to ```<div id="WDGuarantee" ```

Comment: yes, try this here: https://www.bootply.com/lVEuF13r3N

Comment: You lot are stars thankyou ive been scratching my head for hours. thankyou very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you had a invalid ID value used in the referenced target. Remove the "#" from the ID attribute value and you should be good to go.